# Is there a list of failing error codes for MySQL during a bulk insert?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBulkLoader to bulk insert data files in C#. It is configured to continue trying to process any subsequent rows upon error.

MySqlBulkLoader provides an Event Handler (InfoMessage) that will route any errors encountered during the load. The handler code looks like this:

```
void OnInfoMessage(object sender, MySqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) {    
    foreach (var err in e.errors) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{err.Code} {err.Level} {err.Message}");
    }
}
```

And in my data file I introduced some bad data to test with, I get the following 3 errors:

```
1265 Warning Data truncated for column 'LastName' at row 2
1366 Warning Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\xA4\xA3' for column 'City' at row 3
1452 Warning Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`CMData`.`Customer`, CONSTRAINT `Customer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `Company` (`CompanyId`))
```

Note how their 'Level' is always listed as 'Warning', it doesn't differentiate between a failed insert (e.g. FK violation) vs an insert that succeeded but modified the entry (e.g. Data truncated).

Is there a list of error codes for when an insert actually fails. And yes I've looked at the MySQL error documentation, it lists them all and what they're for but doesn't provide any info on the insert failure.

thanks

Comment: I recommend using [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict). Then most warnings become errors. For example, data values are not truncated and inserted. You probably want the actual value, not some other value. This is especially important for numeric values.

Comment: There is no "bulk insert" term on MySQL level. You must look what SQL statement your MySqlBulkLoader is mapped on. From the other side the list of possible errors will be wide enough, and I do not see the reason for to search for it. [Server Error Message Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html) provides server errors list. You may investigate it and think about each error, does it can occur in your process.

Comment: @Bill Karwin - I'd like to try this but I'm curious what happens when the existing DB is not compliant with the setting? e.g. Tables have dates that are 0000-00-00

Comment: Yes, you need to do a lot of testing. It's up to you, if you want to use the benefits of strict mode, you have some work to do. Good thing you know some software engineers! :-)